# Need Python to Return R Squared

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

My regression model is returning coefficients but I cannot figure out how to get it to tell me the R squared and the adjusted R Squared. I need those numbers as well as the coefficient for the intercept. Any insight is appreciated

```
# import the needed libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Import the data
data = pd.read_csv("NBA.csv")

# Specify the features and the target
target = 'Margin'
features = list(data.columns) # This is the column names of your data as a list
features.remove(target) # We remove the target from the list of features

# Train the model
model = LinearRegression() # Instantiate the model
model.fit(data[features].values, data[target].values) # fit the model to the data
print(features) # Returns the name of each feature
print(model.coef_) # Returns the coefficients for each feature (in the same order of your features)
```

Comment: Please always include tags for major Python libraries like Pandas and Scikit-Learn when you are asking about them as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki.

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html): it describes how to retrieve the intercept and calculate R-squared

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
    # import the needed libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Import the data
data = pd.read_csv("NBA.csv")

# Specify the features and the target
target = 'Margin'
features = list(data.columns) # This is the column names of your data as a list
features.remove(target) # We remove the target from the list of features

# Train the model
model = LinearRegression() # Instantiate the model

model.fit(data[features].values, data[target].values) # fit the model to the data
model.score(data[features].values, data[target].values)
print(features) # Returns the name of each feature
print(model.coef_) # Returns the coefficients for each feature (in the same order of your features)
print(model.score(data[features].values, data[target].values))
```